# перенос properties в map

Tags: java, map, properties

Есть файл properties нужно все его значения перевести в Map, как грамотно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("some.properties"));

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String name : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    map.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));
}
```